# How to know if user is using Google Maps?

Tags: android

My app is a reminder app to launch an activity at specific time in the future. As my app request for "Draw Over Screen" permissions, the activity may break the Navigating UI if user are navigating by Google Maps.
I would like to show notification (instead activity) if detect that user are using Google Maps.
I tried with **ActivityManager** to **getRunningTasks** and **getAppTasks** but it always return my app info. (although I am using Google Maps).

Is there any other ways to detect if user are using Google Maps?

Comment: did you try `getRunningAppProcesses` with `ActivityManager`?

Comment: @CôngHải, Yes I tried as well, same result, getting information for my app only.